# Paypal button preloader

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

On internet explorer mostly the paypal button loading time takes about 2-5 seconds. I was wondering if there is a way to place a preloader when the button does not appear.

I already know JS and how to add a preloader, the difficult thing for me is how to catch the event of the button showing in the DOM?

EDIT: The button is echoed via PHP. Here's the code:

```
$str = '<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">'.PHP_EOL;
$str .='<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="'.$_SESSION["user_id"].'">'.PHP_EOL;
$str .='<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="myCensoredUrl">'.PHP_EOL;
$str .='<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">'.PHP_EOL;
$str .='<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="myPayPalCensoredButtonID">'.PHP_EOL;
$str .='<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/he_IL/IL/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - הדרך הקלה והבטוחה לשלם באינטרנט!">'.PHP_EOL;
$str .='<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">'.PHP_EOL;
$str .='</form>'.PHP_EOL;
return $str;
```

EDIT 2: The alt tag doesn't change anything, if your internet is slow the paypal button won't show until communication with their server is done.

Comment: The HTML that is provided by Paypal when you finish creating a button.

Comment: Your question is too broad and unlikely to generate any response. Pls post a minimal viable code in a fiddle to replicate your issue for us to be able to help.

Comment: Are you kidding me? you really want the code to a paypal button? there, i've posted it. :-/

Comment: haven't you heard of an alt tag? that's what it's for..

Comment: @RachelGallen, haven't you heard of checking your comments before you post them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really the alt-tag is specifically designed for this sort of thing but if you really want to catch the image loading event you can do something like this:

```js
function preload() {
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = "https://www.paypalobjects.com/he_IL/IL/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif";

  image.onload = function() {
      var btn = document.getElementById("pay-button");
      btn.setAttribute('src', image.src);
      btn.setAttribute('type', 'image');
  };
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", preload);
```

```html
<form>
    <input id="pay-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Click here to pay now"/>
</form>
```

It will show a regular button and swap it out for the image when it's loaded

Comment: I really don't understand why my question was voted down, it was a valid question. Chris, I have already tried using the ALT tag, it only appears if the image link is broken, which isn't true, the connection just takes time.
In any case, I appreciate your help, thanks!